# How to use or configure Json Patch with collections and IDs in java

Tags: java, jsonpath, json-patch

In java, is it possible to configure the Json patch to perform operation on collections using id object instead of position?

for example:

```
{
   "op": "replace",
   "path": "/collection/0/field",
   "value": test
},
```

to:

```
{
   "op": "replace",
   "path": "/collection/id-of-object/field",
   "value": test
},
```

In this way i can avoid order problems of large ammount of data inside collections.

Thanks.